How do I overwrite inherited method to raise a specific error?
Task:
Create a hierarchy out of birds. Implement four classes:
Class Bird with an attribute name and methods fly and walk.
Class FlyingBird with attributes name, ration, and with the same methods. Ration must have a default value. Implement the method eat, which will describe its typical ration.
Class NonFlyingBird with the same characteristics but obviously without an attribute fly. Add the same "eat" method but with other implementations regarding the swimming bird tastes.
Class SuperBird, which can do all of it: walk, fly, swim and eat. But be careful which "eat" method you inherit.
Implement a str() function call for each class.
Example:
`>>> b = Bird("Any")
>>> b.walk()
"Any bird can walk"

p = NonFlyingBird("Penguin", "fish")
>> p.swim()
"Penguin bird can swim"
>>> p.fly()
AttributeError: 'Penguin' object has no attribute 'fly'
>>> p.eat()
"It eats mostly fish"

c = FlyingBird("Canary")
>>> str(c)
"Canary bird can walk and fly"
>>> c.eat()
"It eats mostly grains"

s = SuperBird("Gull")
>>> str(s)
"Gull bird can walk, swim and fly"
>>> s.eat()
"It eats mostly fish"`

My code:
`class Bird:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def fly(self):
        return f'{self.name} bird can fly'

    def walk(self):
        return f'{self.name} bird can walk'

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.name} bird can walk and fly'


class FlyingBird(Bird):
    def __init__(self, name, ration='grains'):
        super().__init__(name)
        self.ration = ration

    def eat(self):
        return f'It eats mostly {self.ration}'

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.name} bird can walk and fly'


class NonFlyingBird(Bird):
    def __init__(self, name, ration='fish'):
        super().__init__(name)
        self.ration = ration

    def swim(self):
        return f'{self.name} bird can swim'

    def fly(self):
        try:
            raise AttributeError
        except AttributeError as e:
            return e

    def eat(self):
        return f'It eats mostly {self.ration}'

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.name} bird can walk and fly'


class SuperBird:
    pass`

I have not started the SuperBird class I`m trying to resolve the fly() method for NonFlyingBirds. Currently - it returns nothing
Upd: I resolved the task. Thanks!

i might be understanding wrong but, even though you're creating a class Bird with methods, you can make this an abstract class (whether you use abc or just raise NotImplementedError is up to you) so you can just do that in your base class and override what you need in FlyingBird and NonFlyingBird

Since the Bird class is not an abstract class, the children classes may not implement all the methods of the parent class. So you can just skip the fly() method in the NonFlyingBird class.

@TihomirManushev thats wrong. If i skip this class in the NonFlyingBird class - it will just call the parent class method

@KenzoStaelens ok, I`ll try, thnx

also, side note: don't catch and return your errors as is, you should either handle them or raise them as is. If anything else tries to call whatever method that raises an exception but you just return it, the value can be discarded by the program instead of being handled

If the intent is to have a NonFlying bird subclass, then Bird.fly shouldn't exist at all. Classes are better designed with cooperation in mind; subclasses should never remove functionality from a superclass.

The whole eat requirement seems like a very awkward way of demonstrating diamond inheritance. The implication is that SuperBird should inherit from FlyingBird and NonFlyingBird, which is ridiculous on the surface. Bird itself should define eat, FlyingBird should define Fly, a class named SwimmingBird can define swim, and SuperBird can inherit from FlyingBird and SwimmingBird. (The could be a NonFlyingBird class as well for birds that can neither fly nor swim.)

You can raise an AttributeError in the NonFlyingBird class like so:
    def fly(self):
        raise AttributeError(f"'{self.name}' object has no attribute 'fly'")


Thanks, but I need to handle it properly. So it won't break the program executing

Then catch it where you call the code ... Read the docs about error handling in python here: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html.

The naming of the classes is very confusing. Why would you call a class FlyingBird but it doesn't add fly functionality but rather eat functionality?
I will try to clear it up in this python pseudocode.
class Bird:
  def eat()
  def walk()

class FlyingBird(Bird):
  def fly()

class NonFlyingBird(Bird):
  def swim()

This design is cleaner and better shows the intention and provided functionality of each class.
As it goes for SuperBird, which could do everything, in python, you can use concept of multiple inheritance.
class SuperBird(FlyingBird, NonFlyingBird):
  # init call etc ...

With multiple inheritance, you need to be careful not to run into diamond problem, but as far as I know, that shouldn't be a problem in python, since it uses multiple inheritance properly and has ducktyping more on that here.

I need to inherit all classes from the Bird class if I`m not mistaken. The statement is
Create a hierarchy out of birds. Implement four classes. Maybe I need to create Bird -> Flying -> NonFlying -> Super. So Super inherits from all the classes above

It looks to me you are confused about how inheritance is used and what its good for, based on your suggestion here and how you formulate your question. I recommend you to first learn more about inheritance.
